# Vim syntax highlighting for special comments

Tags: vi, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is there a simple way in Vim to extend the syntax highlighting for a language to allow for important comments to stand out? For instance, if a line that starts with `//` denotes a regular comment in a C file, I'd like to have lines starting with `//!!` be highlighted in a more prominent color.

```
// this is a regular comment - line color should be the default color for comments

//!! this is an important comment - highlight line in red
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:syn match specialComment #//!!.*# | hi specialComment ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

---

As Ingo Karkat points out, you can have the commands executing after a `.c` file is loaded by placing them in `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`.

Another option, if you'd like to place everything in a single file, such as `~/.vimrc`, could be to bind the commands to the buffer enter event:

```
au! BufEnter *.c syn match specialComment #//!!.*#  " C files (*.c)
au! BufEnter *.py syn match specialComment /#!!.*/  " Python files (*.py)

...

hi specialComment ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! Can this be automatically set for all _.c_ and _.cpp_ files?

Comment: Put this into `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I ended up splitting it, so that the `syn match specialComment` is defined in the `after/syntax` directory, while the `hi specialComment` is specified in my colorscheme file. That way I can define `specialComments` for all the different languages.

Comment: @IlyaEsteban, added another alternative, if you'd like to keep everything in a single file, such as your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.